# How to know a column store utc time in sql or not

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am working with CDC in sql and we have a table `lsn_timeMapping` and a column inside this table `trans_begintime` its type as mentioned in sql is `datetime`. My question is how can i get to know that whether it stores datetime in utc format or server datetime .

HERE is [image: how data is submitted in cdc] a flow mentioned in msdn

Comment: How is the table populated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear that the time is stored based upon the server's locale settings(local timezone). Therefore, it will not be UTC unless the server timezone is set to UTC.

Source: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/533689/store-utc-in-lsn-time-mapping